# Log to user accounts Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am working on an application using Firebase and Node as Back-End.
My app has an admin access and I want to create temporary access to users accounts.
I also wanted to have a history of all the logins on users account with infos such as web browser, localisation etc... for security purposes.

My idea is to create a one time use temporary auth token for an user and give it to the auth function from Firebase.
But I want to stay connected as an Admin still, so I thought about an iFrame inside the main window.

I am having trouble finding infos on the web, wanted to know if you had any leads or better ideas/way to do it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication on its own does not provide a log of user sign-in actions, but with the new, optional Firebase Authentication with Identity upgrade you get <kbd>User activity and audit logging</kbd>. From the [feature overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform-features):

> **User activity and audit logging**
>
> Monitor and log administrative access and end-user activity.
>
> When you upgrade your project, you automatically enable admin activity audit logs in Cloud Logging. You can also enable user activity logging on the [Authentication Settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings) page of the Firebase console.
>
> To learn how to view and analyze your logs, see the [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs) documentation.

---

[Creating a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for the user you want to impersonate and then using that to [sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) should work. If you want to sign in with two different users, you can create two instance of `FirebaseApp`, and sign in to the `auth` member for each user.

Comment: Firebase Auth with id Upgrade seems awesome ! 
I can use it to create log of sign-in actions, but I think it won't tell me who created the token used to sign-in I guess ? 
I will have to create a cloud function which logs the user creating the token alongside the account concerned.
But these are great ideas ! I will keep the post updated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have an admin app where I'm connected. I have my main app (where I want to log as an user) the token must be used only on the principal app (not admin, since the user does not have the rights and can't be bugged).
But the problem is that I can be logged on the main app, this is why I thought about an iFrame in the admin app for the main app. I don't think I can create an instance of the Main FirebaseApp alongside the admin app (I already got an error like that "FirebaseApp already running")

Comment: 1) You could [embed a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) into the token with info on who created it. 2) You can have multiple projects without an iframe. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#web. If you can't get that to work based on the link, I recommend opening another question [showing what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello !
For the token creation part, it's working. The log-in part also. Now I must make this token temporary and fix the autoredirection to the classic login page when someone isn't logged and everything will work like a charm !

Comment: Hello Frank, everything works. But I wanted to know if I can make the token one-time use?